# Populating an Array with 1-100 with A86 Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, dos, a86

I am trying to write an assembly program that uses a procedure to populate an array with values 1-100. The code that I have so far is as follows:

```
jmp main

first100 dw 100 dup (?)

main:
call prepare
call populate
mov ax, first100[0]
call putDec

mov ah, 04c
int 021
include ioProcs.inc

prepare:
mov ax, 1
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 100
ret

populate:
mov first100[bx], ax
inc ax
inc bx
loop populate
ret
```

However, the first value in the array first100 turns into 513 as opposed to 1. It is probably something simple, but where am I messing up?
Thank you much for your time.

Comment: You need to increment `bx` by 2, because addressing uses byte offsets and your items are 2 bytes each.

Comment: @Deleteme Please do not edit your questions in this manner. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account for proper procedure.

Comment: @JasonC have been trying, no one is processing the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jester mentioned you need to increment `bx` by two bytes in the populate loop.

You are creating an array of type `dw`, that is a word. It has a size of two bytes.